# Calculate timedifference in one cell excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm currently working on an Excel document to make scheduling easier.

I want to have a full week in a small tabel, where i put in my check in time and check out time in a single cell.

So lets say i have a work week:

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08.00-16:00 | 08.00-16:00 | 08.00-16:00 | 08.00-18:22 | 08.00-13:00 |

Here i want to have a cell for totals:

So it have

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08.00-16:00 | 08.00-16:00 | 08.00-16:00 | 08.00-18:22 | 08.00-13:00 | =((a2-timediff)+(b2-timediff)... |

Is this possible?

[Current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWLzM.png)

Comment: Possible, yes, but it's much better practice to have one value in one cell.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot have the start and end times in separate cells? It would make things a lot easier

Comment: I know it might be better practice to have 1-1, but i need it to be easy to write down, and the one making the workshift currently is using tables inside of word. And she just wants to be able to write e.x. "10-16 *tab* 10-17 *tab* 9:45-19 *tab*" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2:E2,".",":"),FIND("-",A2:E2)+1,LEN(A2:E2))-LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:E2,".",":"),FIND("-",A2:E2)-1))
```

[image]

With LET to shorten:

```
=LET(rng, A2:E2,sub,SUBSTITUTE(rng,".",":"),fnd,FIND("-",rng),SUMPRODUCT(MID(sub,fnd+1,LEN(rng))-LEFT(sub,fnd-1)))
```

Also I had to use substitute because `hh.mm` is not a recognized time format in my local settings.  If it is a recognized format in yours you can skip that step.

Comment: I've inserted this into my cell: 
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C8:I8;".";":");FIND("-";C8:I8)+1;LEN(C8:I8))-LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(C8:I8;".";":");FIND("-";C8:I8)-1))
But the value just says "#VALUE!"

Comment: Then you data does not match what you posted, as you can see it works for the data you gave.

Comment: I've put in: "10.00-18.30" in 7 cells. I've edited the post with an image of my current table

Comment: It works for me: https://imgur.com/a/qqgRGaV

Comment: If you were to type the time in a cell by itself, would you type: `12:30` or `12.30`

Comment: Our timestamps would be "12:30". And i found out that because the cell is formatted (so it's c:9 & c:10), it messes up.

But now i've stumpeled upon another issue. being, i don't get the right output.

Having 3x"10.00-18:30" makes "1.0625" but expected: "28.5"

Comment: Then multiply the result by 24 or format the output as `[hh]:mm`